# Finding the weak form of a PDE with a tensor argument

Tags: finite-element, pde, computational-physics, weak-solution

I am trying to solve for the order parameter ($A$) in the Ginzburg Landau equations. I had [asked on the math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466889/finding-the-weak-form-of-a-pde-with-a-tensor-argument) site but was recommended to ask here.
We are trying to solve the following equation, (with the implied sum over $j$, for each component identified by $\mu$, $i$), $K_i$, $\beta_i$, and $\alpha (T)$ are known parameters (constants wrt position),
$$
K_1 \partial^2_j A_{\mu i} + K_{23} \partial_i (\partial_j A_{\mu j}) = 2 \beta_1 Tr(AA^T) A_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_2 Tr(AA^\dagger)A_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_3[AA^TA]_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_4[AA^\dagger A]_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_5[AA^TA]_{\mu i} + \alpha(T) Tr(AA^\dagger) = (\text{rhs})_{\mu i},
$$
assuming,
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{uu} & A_{uv} & A_{uw} \\
A_{vu} & A_{vv} & A_{vw} \\
A_{wu} & A_{wv} & A_{ww}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I have a code in C++ that implements the FDM with relaxation, but we have found that our mixed derivative approximations have large enough error that the code doesn't always converge to a solution. We are looking at the option of using others' FEM solvers (like [FreeFEM](https://doc.freefem.org/introduction/index.html) or [MOOSE](https://mooseframework.inl.gov/index.html)), but I'm having a hard time getting the weak form of our set of equations. I am following the description [here](https://mooseframework.inl.gov/getting_started/examples_and_tutorials/tutorial01_app_development/step04_weak_form.html#step-4-generate-a-weak-form), and obtained
$$
0 = K_1 \oint_{\Gamma} {\psi \vec{\nabla}A_{\mu i} \cdot \hat{n}}
- K_1 \int_{\Omega} {\vec{\nabla} \psi \cdot \vec{\nabla}A_{\mu i}}
- \int_{\Omega} {\psi (\text{rhs})_{\mu i}}
+ K_{23}\int_{\Omega} {\psi \partial_i (\partial_j A_{\mu j})},
$$
but I don't know how to get the last term. I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949359/finding-the-weak-form-of-a-coupled-set-of-equations) and thought that maybe I'd have to explicitly write out all 9 equations and use 9 test functions?

**My main question is: can this system of equations be reasonably written for a FEM solver? If so, how?**

I played around with the equations a little more and figured I could write them generally as,
$$
(\text{rhs})_{\mu i} = K_1 \vec{\nabla}^2 A_{\mu i} + K_{23} \partial_i \Big[ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}_{\mu;r} \Big],
$$
where $\vec{A}_{\mu;r}$ is the vector formed from the $\mu$-th row of $A$ (is there a better way to represent that?). (A note here: the rows and columns of the order parameter do not necessarily correspond to spatial variables, and for our ultimate goal will be in cylindrical coordinates; so it may not be a good idea to represent this as a vector.) Thus,
$$
0 = K_1 \oint_{\Gamma} {\psi \vec{\nabla}A_{\mu i} \cdot \hat{n}}
- K_1 \int_{\Omega} {\vec{\nabla} \psi \cdot \vec{\nabla}A_{\mu i}}
- \int_{\Omega} {\psi (\text{rhs})_{\mu i}}
+ K_{23}\int_{\Omega} {\psi \partial_i \Big[ \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{A}_{\mu;r} \Big]},
$$
which might be easier (or more obvious how) to integrate by parts? So, would I still have to use 9 test functions? We expect the solution function for each element to be different, so I might still need to have all 9 separately...

Trying a slightly different approach: taking the last term, $K_{23}\int_{\Omega} {\psi \partial_i (\partial_j A_{\mu j})}$, explicitly writing out the sum over $j$, and using the product rule, we can say,
$$
K_{23}\int_{\Omega} {\psi \partial_i (\partial_j A_{\mu j})} \to K_{23} \sum_{j=u,v,w}{ \Bigg[ \int_{\Omega}{\partial_i (\psi \partial_j A_{\mu j})} - \int_{\Omega}{(\partial_i \psi)(\partial_j A_{\mu j})} \Bigg] }
$$

The first term here ($\int_{\Omega}{\partial_i (\psi \partial_j A_{\mu j})}$) looks like the divergence term that we previously rewrote as a boundary integral...except that there are no vectors. **Is this now in the right form so that I can use it in a FEM solver?**

After applying the product rule, I found that I could select a different order of derivatives (because these derivative operators commute, right?) and instead obtain,
$$
\to K_{23} \Bigg[ \int_{\Omega}{ \vec{\nabla} \cdot (\psi \partial_i \vec{A}_{\mu;r})} - \sum_{j=u,v,w}{ \int_{\Omega}{(\partial_j \psi)(\partial_i A_{\mu j})} \Bigg] }
$$
Now the first term could be rewritten using the divergence theorem? (Again, assuming that $\vec{A}_{\mu;r}$ can be treated as a "normal" vector.)

Comment: Variational principles are easier to convert to FE form.  An example (similar to Laudau-Ginzburg): https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3928958/

Comment: For anyone who may be interested, uranix gave a [great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4467463/954589).

Comment: The weak form part of my question was answered by uranix, but I'm still looking for how I can implement it in some FE solver (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41438/what-fem-solver-should-be-used-for-matrix-valued-fe-spaces), if anyone has ideas...

Comment: Do you have a reference for the problem you're working on? I always thought the Ginzburg-Landau equation was for a complex scalar field rather than for a complex 3x3 matrix.

Comment: @DanielShapero, there are several papers I have been learning from (only one of which is free to the public): https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10909-016-1632-7, https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.045301, https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.92.144515, (the free one ->) https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.7308. As you will find in these papers, we are solving the GL equations for He-3, which has quite a complicated order parameter!