# What FEM solver should be used for matrix-valued FE spaces?

Tags: finite-element, pde, computational-physics

I am pretty new to using FE solvers. I am trying to solve a system of (up to) 9 complex equations. We write these as a matrix equation ([here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41430/finding-the-weak-form-of-a-pde-with-a-tensor-argument)), (with the implied sum over $j$, for each component identified by $\mu$, $i$), and known parameters (or at least constant wrt position): $K_i$, $\beta_i$, and $\alpha (T)$;
$$
K_1 \partial^2_j A_{\mu i} + K_{23} \partial_i (\partial_j A_{\mu j}) = 2 \beta_1 Tr(AA^T) A_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_2 Tr(AA^\dagger)A_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_3[AA^TA]_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_4[AA^\dagger A]_{\mu i} + 2 \beta_5[AA^TA]_{\mu i} + \alpha(T) Tr(AA^\dagger) = (\text{rhs})_{\mu i},
$$
assuming,
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{uu} & A_{uv} & A_{uw} \\
A_{vu} & A_{vv} & A_{vw} \\
A_{wu} & A_{wv} & A_{ww}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

[Thanks to uranix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4467463/954589), I have the weak form of the equations,
$$
-K_1 \int_{\Omega} (\partial_j \psi_{\mu i}) (\partial_j A_{\mu i}) d\Omega
-K_{23} \int_{\Omega} (\partial_i \psi_{\mu i}) (\partial_j A_{\mu j}) d\Omega\\
+K_1 \int_{\Gamma} \psi_{\mu i} n_j (\partial_j A_{\mu i}) d\Gamma
+K_{23} \int_{\Gamma} \psi_{\mu i} n_i (\partial_j A_{\mu j}) d\Gamma
= \int_{\Omega} \psi_{\mu i} ({\rm rhs})_{\mu i} d\Omega.
$$

**Question: What FE solver would be the best to solve this set of equations?**

I have been learning [FreeFEM](https://doc.freefem.org/introduction/index.html), and it seems like it can do this by using "vectorial FE spaces" (like they briefly mention [here](https://doc.freefem.org/documentation/finite-element.html#vector-valued-fe-function)), and define functions to convert between arrays and matrices. I have been unsuccessful in declaring the trial and test functions as members of such a "vectorial FE space." Does FreeFEM have anything else like it that I could use? I have also done a little with [MOOSE](https://mooseframework.inl.gov/), but I'm not sure how I could make it work. I looked into [deal.II](https://www.dealii.org/current/readme.html), and it looks like I could totally make it work, even if I have to build my own class in C++, but it doesn't build right with CMake (complains that it can't find some serialization library in Boost). The last one I've looked at is [NGSolve](https://ngsolve.org/), and [one person talked about a system of 5 equations](https://ngsolve.org/forum/ngspy-forum/1578-assembling-with-a-vector-valued-fe-space-with-5-components), and [here](https://docu.ngsolve.org/latest/i-tutorials/unit-2.9-fourthorder/fourthorder.html?highlight=matrix%20valued) the documentation mention a "matrix-valued function." I just don't want to download and build yet another FEM solver if it might not work.

Comment: For what concerns your problem with CMake, you may ask for help in the deal.II mailing list (https://groups.google.com/g/dealii)

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly standard elliptic problem (the operator is of the form $-\Delta - \text{grad}\,\text{div}$). It is vector-valued (in fact matrix-valued) in the same way as the elasticity equations are vector-valued.

deal.II does these sorts of things quite easily (disclaimer: I'm one of the deal.II authors), as I'm sure many other libraries do. I would start by taking a look at the following page that provides an overview of how deal.II does vector-valued problems: https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/group__vector__valued.html
You might then want to take a look at the step-8, step-20, and step-22 tutorial programs for more examples, though step-8 is probably closest to what you want to do.

The difficulties one might encounter for the equation you're after are:

- You state that $A$ is a matrix quantity, but is there any requirement that it be a *symmetric* matrix? This substantially complicates the choice of finite element spaces.
- The original equation you wrote down is nonlinear. You'll need to write a solver that turns the nonlinear problem into a sequence of linear problems, for example using a Newton method. I would suggest you take a look at deal.II's step-15 tutorial program for that.

Comment: deal.II did look very promising! I'll have to see if I can find help with the CMake problems. And unfortunately, $A$ is not always symmetric. The systems that we are solving have some kinds of symmetry (like just in the form/structure of $A$), but $A_{uw}$ and $A_{wu}$ sometimes will be quite different.

Comment: And, I forgot to mention that we would like to eventually solve some systems in cylindrical coordinates...can deal.II solve non-Cartesian systems?

Comment: The fact that you are looking for non-symmetric solutions actually makes it easier because enforcing symmetries is hard. As for coordinate systems: Yes, that only leads to a slightly different weak formulation (every integral will be over $r,\phi$ instead of $x,y$ and will have an extra $2\pi r$ as a weight in the integral.